# Website doesnt scale properly when switched to landscape on phones

Tags: html, css, ipad, scaling, mobile-website

I have created a responsive website that has desktop and mobile versions, using @media. Everything works perfectly, apart from when you view the website on a landscape phone or on an ipad.

Here's the website: http://netcomtb.esy.es/home.html

If you press f12 and view the site in mobile it looks fine, but if you view it in ipad, or any landscape phone you will see what I mean, I just dont know how to explain it so it's pretty difficult to find a solution!

The first picture is what the desktop version of the site looks like, the second image is what the mobile site looks like on a nexus 6P, and the third picture is what the site looks like when the phone is in landscape mode.

I couldnt upload 3 images so I stuck all 3 into the same one:

[Images here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJI8f.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question isn't very clear. What **exactly** is the problem? On mobile, I see the second section only have 25% width. Is that the problem? On iPad, the content slightly overlaps the header? Is that the problem? We can't be sure what the problem as, as we don't know what look you're trying to **accomplish**. Please update your question so that you clearly state the desired look, and what isn't desired. For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Lumia 950 (10.0.14393) here and website looks fine except datetime labels on landscape. Is this the same problem that you are talking about?[image]
Also #listingcontainer div look weird (probably label font size is too big)

Comment: Sorry I forgot about that page haha, click on home.html, thats the website im talking about :)

Comment: It would be much better if you provide a screenshot and show which part bothers you. :)